# Having issue with Eye Dropper of Google Chrome from Inspect Elements area in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, google-chrome-devtools, color-picker, ubuntu-22.04

[image: Eye dropper screenshot in Inspect Elements of Google chrome]

Whenever I need to pick a colour using eyedropper from styles section of inspect element of google chrome, I gets below shown window pop-up.

[image: Screen share window pop-up]

Whatever I decide to go with either share or cancel, I gets dissapointments. It does not let me pick the colour.

Sharing My system details,
[image: System Details]

[image: Chrome Details]

I am not able to find any solution neither Google Forum nor Ubuntu community.
Is this happening only with me? Is there anyone who knows solution for it?